# How can I make tiki torch holders from PVC pipe or equivalent?

Tags: lighting, outdoor, pvc

I have a plan to attach some short segments of PVC piping to a pool fence and use them as holders for tiki torches. These are the questions that I'm trying to find answers to:

1. Can you suggest something better than a (say) one foot piece of PVC piping as a tiki torch holder on a pool fence?
2. How would you attach the PVC piping to the pool fence? (I feel that cable ties might slip over time.)
3. Where is the best place to buy PVC piping in short segments or which shop will cut it for you?

(I'm located in Phoenix, AZ)

Comment: Of what construction is the pool fence?  How many Torches do you want to mount?

Comment: PVC is a thermoplastic so be certain you have enough heat sink around your torches. It'd be a shame if transfered heat softened the pipe to the point that your torches fell over and started the fence on fire.

Comment: The pool fence is metal. Planning on mounting around 10 torches.

Comment: how warm do these torches get?

Comment: The cans get very hot but the torches (structures) that hold the can are made of bamboo which is what will be in contact with the PVC and does not get hot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think PVC piping would be fine. You can even paint it any color you like.

Alternatively, you could attach the torches themselves to the fence, but with the piping, you can remove the torches in Winter.

I would think cable ties would be fine, or clamps as shirlock suggests. IMO the trick would be to make sure the pipes don't slide up and down and come out of the fasteners. You could drill a hole in the pipe segments, and cable tie that to a horizontal piece of the fence to combat this.

Most hardware stores will have a variety of PCV piping. If the PVC pipe is thing enough (which it should be if these are not huge tiki torches), you can get a special cutter for them, which is sort of a curved pair of scissors. Makes it a piece of cake to get straight cuts. If it is thicker, any saw will do, as PVC is generally very soft.

Comment: Winter? in Phoenix? Really? :) Sorry, getting crotchety because its still quite Winter like here in the Rockies :( Carry on.

Answer (score 3):

PVC pipe especially schedule 40 would be super strong.  Attach them to the fence with some stainless steel hose clamps.(hardware dept)  PVC  is so easy to cut, any saw will do. If you go to Home Depot, they got saws you can use in the millwork dept.  Just cut up your lengths there.  Case closed!  lol